# ActionCable. Redis reconnect failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

While testing RoR 5.0 beta and actionCable I had this error in console.

`[ActionCable] Redis reconnect failed.e`

After that install this Redis by using HomeBrew. But nothing happens. How to fix it?

OS X. Rails 5 beta.

Comment: Is Redis running? Can you verify that the port Rails expects it on is the port it's running on?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `redis-server` in a different command line tab.
You should see something like this:

[image]

After that start your rails application again. If your redis configuration and installation are ok, it should work.

Comment: If this does not work edit the question with the redis configuration.